# C++14: How to group variadic inputs by template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, c++14, template-meta-programming

Say I have two classes:

```
template <unsigned N>
class Pixel {
    float color[N];
public:
    Pixel(const std::initializer_list<float> &il)
    {
      // Assume this code can create a Pixel object from exactly N floats, and would throw a compiler error otherwise

    }
};

template <unsigned N>
class PixelContainer {
    std::vector<Pixel<N>> container;
};
```

What I'm trying to do is to write a constructor for `PixelContainer` such that:
It would instantiate correctly for the following cases (example, not exhaustive):

```
PixelContainer<3> pc1(1, 2, 3)          // Creates a container containing one Pixel<3> objects
PixelContainer<3> pc2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) // Creates a container containing 2 Pixel<3> objects
PixelContainer<2> pc3(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) // Creates a container containing 3 Pixel<2> objects
```

It would not compile for the following cases (as example, not exhaustive):

```
PixelContainer<3> pc4(2, 3) // Not enough arguments
PixelContainer<2> pc5(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // Too many arguments
```

How do I achieve the above using template meta-programming? I feel it should be achievable, but can't figure out how. Specifically, I do **not** want to be doing the grouping myself e.g

```
PixelContainer<2> pc2({1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}) // Creates a container containing 3 Pixel<2> objects
```

(See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17607080/212942) for the inspiration behind mine)

Comment: In the last snippet, surely you meant `PixelContainer<2>` and "containing 3 Pixel<2> objects"?

Comment: Exactly, corrected! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T, std::size_t I, std::size_t...Offs, class Tup>
T create( std::index_sequence<Offs...>, Tup&& tup ) {
  return T( std::get<I+Offs>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))... );
}

template <unsigned N>
struct Pixel {
    float color[N];

    template<class...Ts,
        std::enable_if_t< sizeof...(Ts)==N, bool > = true
    >
    Pixel(Ts&&...ts):color{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... } {};
};

template <unsigned N>
struct PixelContainer {

    std::vector<Pixel<N>> container;
    template<class T0, class...Ts,
      std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T0>, PixelContainer>{}, bool> =true
    >
    PixelContainer(T0&& t0, Ts&&...ts):
      PixelContainer( std::make_index_sequence<(1+sizeof...(Ts))/N>{}, std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<T0>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... ) )
    {}
    PixelContainer() = default;
private:
  template<class...Ts, std::size_t...Is>
  PixelContainer( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::tuple<Ts&&...>&& ts ):
    container{ create<Pixel<N>, Is*N>( std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::move(ts) )... }
  {}
};
```

`create` takes a type, a starting index, and a index sequence of offsets.  Then it takes a tuple.

It then creates the type from the (starting index)+(each of the offsets) and returns it.

We use this in the private ctor of `PixelContainer`.  It has an index sequence element for each of the Pixels whose elements are in the `tuple`.

We multiply the index sequence element by N, the number of elements per index sequence, and pass that to create.  Also, we pass in an index sequence of 0,...,N-1 for the offsets, and the master tuple.

We then unpack that into a `{}` enclosed ctor for `container`.

The public ctor just forwards to the private ctor with the right pack of indexes of one-per-element (equal to argument count/N).  It has some SFINAE annoyance `enable_if_t` stuff to avoid it swallowing stuff that should go to a copy ctor.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85a8278160c46f1f).

Also,

```
  std::enable_if_t<0 == ((sizeof...(Ts)+1)%N), bool> =true
```

could be a useful SFINAE addition to `PixelContainer`'s public ctor.

Without it, we simply round down and discard "extra" elements passed to `PixelContainer`.  With it, we get a "no ctor found" if we have extra elements (ie, not a multiple of N).

Comment: I think OP would appreciate some enlightenment to why and how it works.

Comment: The name of the offset pack for `create` is inconsistent, should be `Is`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken If one seeks enlightenment, one should seek to become budda.  If one seeks confusion, one should learn C++.

Comment: @Pezo Fixed!  Made it `Offs` because they are offsets.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - The answer taught me so many `std::` constructs in one post! Can you elaborate on the last edit, about the SFINAE addition to the public actor (and where it might be useful) ? Thanks for refining the answer and the live example!

Comment: @TCSGrad It means that you'll get "no constructor found" if you don't pass a multiple-of-N to the PixelContainer ctor, instead of silently dropping elements or generating an error deep within template expansions.

Answer (score 3):

Made something as well, which relies more on compiler optimizations for performance than @Yakk's answer.

It uses temporary `std::array`s. `temp` is used to store the passed values somewhere. `temp_pixels` is used to copy pixel data from `temp`. Finally `temp` is copied into `container`.

I believe that those arrays *do* get optimized away, but I'm not certain. Looking at godbolt it seems that they are but I am not good at reading compiler assembly output :)

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

template <unsigned N>
struct Pixel {
    float color[N]; // consider std::array here
};

template <unsigned N>
class PixelContainer {
    std::vector<Pixel<N>> container;

public:
    template<class... Ts>
    PixelContainer(Ts... values)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) % N == 0, "Pixels should be grouped by 3 values in PixelContainer constructor");
        const std::array<float, sizeof...(Ts)> temp{float(values)...};
        std::array<Pixel<N>, sizeof...(Ts) / N> temp_pixels{};

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Ts); i += N)
        {
            auto& pixel = temp_pixels[i / N];

            std::copy(
                temp.begin() + i, temp.begin() + i + N,
                pixel.color
            );
        }

        container = std::vector<Pixel<N>>(temp_pixels.begin(), temp_pixels.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    PixelContainer<3> pc1(1, 2, 3);          // Creates a container containing one Pixel<3> objects
    PixelContainer<3> pc2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // Creates a container containing 2 Pixel<3> objects
    PixelContainer<2> pc3(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // Creates a container containing 3 Pixel<2> objects

/*
    PixelContainer<3> pc4(2, 3); // Not enough arguments
    PixelContainer<2> pc5(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // Too many arguments
*/
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative approach that's simpler to read. Thanks for the alternative viewpoint!

Answer (score 1):

I would propose some hybrid version, there is still a temporary array, but no temporary for pixels

```
template <unsigned N>
struct PixelContainer {

    template<std::size_t S, std::size_t... elts>
    auto createOne(const std::array<float, S> &arr, std::size_t offset,
                   std::index_sequence<elts...>) {
        return Pixel<N>{ arr[offset + elts]... };
    }

    template<typename... Floats>
    PixelContainer(Floats... vals) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(vals) % N == 0, "invalid number of args");
        std::array<float, sizeof...(vals)> arr = { float(vals)... };
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(vals) / N; i++) {
            container.push_back(createOne(arr, i * N, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));
        }

    }
    std::vector<Pixel<N>> container;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is pretty much given in the link you provided ([C++ number of function's parameters fixed by template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607080/c-number-of-functions-parameters-fixed-by-template-parameter)). You just need to change the assert there: instead of `sizeof...(Floats) == N` you'll want `sizeof...(Floats) % N == 0`.

Comment: That doesn't show me how to group the inputs so that I can instantiate the Pixel objects one by one. Let me try to edit the question to reflect that.